# ETX4-fs error on startup

Tags: ext4, fsck, sd-card

[image]

Hi everybody, today I run `dmesg` and at the bottom I found some error lines about the device mmcblk0p2. Everything works fine even with those errors but I'd like to understand the problem.

I've googled and I've found that many people solved the problem by running `e2fsck -b block_number /dev/sdb` with all the block_number(s) listed running `sudo mke2fs -n /dev/xxx` but the answer is always that my super-block is corrupt.

I don't know if it is important but I did it by inserting the sd-card in a pc running debian and I unmounted /media/fc25...(that should be the filesystem) and usb1 (that should be the boot) because otherwise it said the /dev/sdb was in use.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to fix your problem but I know fsck is normally used to repair file system problems in linux. http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck